# ARM template, Incorrect Segment Lengths

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-rm-template

I'm trying to build an ARM template and keep getting the error:

```
'The template resource 'udr-sub-w05-w05-w05-agw-10.10.10.32/27' for type 
'Microsoft.Network/routeTables' at line '141' and column '5' has incorrect segment lengths. A nested resource type must have identical number of segments as its resource name. A root resource type must 
have segment length one greater than its resource name.
```

The nested template for create route tables code is below:

```
{
      "name": "[variables('routeTable1')]",
      "type": "Microsoft.Network/routeTables",
      "apiVersion": "[variables('routeTableApiVersion')]",
      "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
      "properties": {
        "routes": [
        ],
        "disableBgpRoutePropagation": false
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "[variables('routeTable2')]",
      "type": "Microsoft.Network/routeTables",
      "apiVersion": "[variables('routeTableApiVersion')]",
      "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
      "properties": {
        "routes": [
        ],
        "disableBgpRoutePropagation": false
      }
    },
```

Any idea where this is going wrong? I've spent some time googling and my understanding is the "TYPE" should have one less segment than the "NAME", which I believe it has

```
  "name": "[variables('routeTable1')]",
  "type": "Microsoft.Network/routeTables",
```

Route table one variables

```
 "routeTable1": "[tolower(concat('udr-', variables('subnetName1')))]",
 "routeTable2": "[tolower(concat('udr-', variables('subnetName2')))]",
```

Thanks

Comment: If you read the file on the code editor, which are the line 141? and how you define the variable "routeTable1"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your route table name contains `/`, hence it thinks you are trying to create a sub resource and asks you to provide its type (you only provide parent resource type). remove the `/27` thing or replace it with `-27` or something like that.

Comment: I'd mixed up the parameter file, thanks for clearing that up :)